# What does "making it on my own" mean?

Tags: idioms

In my English class students need to describe many phrases. One of them is "making it on my own". This is not from a reading, so I can't really guess the meaning from the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

The phrase *on my own* generally means "by myself, without assistance from other people."

The real tricky part of this would be the *making it* part. The phrase *making it* could refer to the construction of something, such as a potter making a set of plates, or a woodworker building a table and chairs. For example:

> Is anyone helping you make that kitchen set?
>   No, I'm *making it on my own*.

However, that's probably **not** the intended meaning here. Another meaning of the phrase *making it* is "getting by in life" – that is, paying your living expenses and supporting yourself. Generally speaking, to *make it on your own* means you have a decent job, you're paying your own rent, you're buying your own food, and you're paying your own bills. For example:

> Does your daughter Nancy still live at home?
>   No, she moved out last year. She's *making it on her own*.

That would mean that Nancy is living like an adult, and doesn't get much assistance from her parents.

I suspect that's the meaning being sought after.

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome aboard. You might want to [read this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer), though.

Comment: I'm so sorry for that. I am very new to this site, but I'll keep that in mind next time I ask a question.

Comment: No need to be sorry! Just trying to give you a tip for next time.